# Re-arrange List of Tuple in Python

Tags: python, list

Here, I have a list of tuple as in the following format:

```
mylist = [('t1', 0, 23),
          ('t1', 1, 24),
          ('t1', 2, 25),
          ('t2', 0, 22),
          ('t2', 1, 25),
          ('t2', 2, 26)]
```

Now, I would like to arrange the list in a way such that it could be save into a CSV file as shown in the following fomart:

```
  t1 t2
0 23 22
1 24 25
2 25 26
```

What should I do?

Comment: It's not quite the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm lazy so I use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [('t1', 0, 23),
          ('t1', 1, 24),
          ('t1', 2, 25),
          ('t2', 0, 22),
          ('t2', 1, 25),
          ('t2', 2, 26)]


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['t1','t2'], index=[0,1,2])

print df
#    t1   t2
#0  NaN  NaN
#1  NaN  NaN
#2  NaN  NaN

for col, row, val in mylist:
    df[col][row] = val

print df
#   t1  t2
#0  23  22
#1  24  25
#2  25  26

#df.to_csv('filename.csv') # comma separated values
df.to_csv('filename.csv', sep=' ')
```

---

EDIT:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [('t1', 0, 23),
          ('t1', 1, 24),
          ('t1', 2, 25),
          ('t2', 0, 22),
          ('t2', 1, 25),
          ('t2', 2, 26)]


df = pd.DataFrame()

for col, row, val in mylist:
    if col not in df.columns:
        #df[col] = pd.Series() # new column with NaN
        df[col] = 0 # new column with zeros

    if row not in df.index:
        #df.loc[row] = pd.Series() # new row with NaN
        df.loc[row] = 0 # new row with zeros

    df[col][row] = val

print df
#   t1  t2
#0  23  22
#1  24  25
#2  25  26

df.to_csv('filename.csv', sep=' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here you are hard code the column and index. But what if the columns('t1', 't2') are to be read from the list, as well as the index (0, 1, 2)?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is the best way.

If you cannot use Pandas, you can use the [cvs module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
mylist = [('t1', 0, 23),
('t1', 1, 24),
('t1', 2, 25),
('t2', 0, 22),
('t2', 1, 25),
('t2', 2, 26)]

import csv

di={}
for t in mylist:
    di.setdefault(t[0], []).append(t[2])

with open(fn, 'w') as cf:
    w=csv.writer(cf)
    w.writerow(['index']+di.keys())
    line=0
    for t in zip(*di.values()):
        w.writerow([line]+list(t))
        line+=1
```

File is then:

```
index,t2,t1
0,22,23
1,25,24
2,26,25
```

If order in the list of `t1, t2` is relevant, use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of dict.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that doesn't use `loc`:

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [('t1', 0, 23),
          ('t1', 1, 24),
          ('t1', 2, 25),
          ('t2', 0, 22),
          ('t2', 1, 25),
          ('t2', 2, 26)]
firstkey = mylist[0][0]
mydict = {}
indices = []
for key, index, val in mylist:
    try:
        mydict[key].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        mydict[key] = [val]
    if key == firstkey:
        indices.append(index)
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
df.index = indices
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```